# Npm dependencies not installed through chef

Tags: node.js, npm, chef-infra, chef-recipe

We are trying to resolve node dependencies using 'npm install' in chef recipe through execute resource.

This my chef recipe :

```
execute "download dependancies from package.json" do
 command "npm install --silent"
 user "#{node['non_root_user']}"
end
```

This is my package json :

```js
"dependencies": {
"classnames": "^2.2.5",
"keymirror": "^0.1.1",
"moment": "^2.10.2",
"moment-timezone": "^0.4.0",
"node-sass": "^3.2.0",
"parse": "^1.4.2",
"react": "^0.13.2",
"react-swipeable": "^3.0.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-eslint": "^4.0.10",
"brfs": "^1.4.0",
"browser-sync": "^2.6.7",
"browserify": "^9.0.7",
"browserify-shim": "^3.8.5",
"classnames": "^2.2.5",
"dotenv": "^1.2.0",
"eslint": "^1.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^3.2.3",
```

`npm install` only installs `dev-dependencies` but not `dependencies`. is there any automated way to install all dependencies using `npm install`? Am I missing anything additional configuration with npm.

Comment: Try using the `--only=production` option with `npm install`.

Comment: If I use `--only=production`  it will only install `dependencies` not `dev-dependencies`  is it correct?. Ideailly it should install all `dependencies` and `dev-dependencies` isn't it with `npm install`?

Comment: How do you know 'npm install' command is not installing all depencies? I think 'npm install ' should intall devDepencies and dependencies

Comment: Ideally it should install both.But When I tried to build the code the some of dependencies were missing for like `gulp` was missing `browser-sync` so I couldn't build the project. Also I found node_modules were missing. so it seems like `npm install` is inconsistent

Comment: maybe try it without `--silent` to see if there's any output that would indicate what's going on?

Comment: Are you sure you ran `npm install` in the right directory? The command you're looking for is `npm install` which installs all dependencies. If what you tried is not working then my guess is you're executing it without `cd`ing into the correct directory

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine so there is probably some other issue. If you want something simpler check out the poise-javascript and application_javascript cookbooks though.